# Convert DD-Mon-YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to convert dt_of_birth `[varchar] (15)` which is in the format `DD-Mon-YYYY` to `DD/MM/YYYY`.

`dt_of _birth` is specified in different table and the conversion had to be done and stored in another table which has the same column name as `dt_of_birth`.

Comment: [MSDN article about CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) including the format codes.

Comment: I always use http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: See the official convert format list at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23/10/2016', 103) -- dd/mm/yyyy
```

Comment: Read the linked article. It's a style number that determines to which date format SQL Server should format to.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '23-Oct-2016', 13), 103);
```

`103` is for `dd/mm/yyyy` format

Check out this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp?output=print)

Comment: How do i get the dates which i already have in my table in the place of '23-Oct-2016'?

Comment: I am sorry but I could not understand your problem clearly but you can simply get them using a 'select' statement and then convert them

Comment: i have a date field in my table and i need to convert and store it in another table

Comment: Try something like this:-INSERT INTO Table2(Column2)
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '23-Oct-2016', 13), 103) FROM Table1

Comment: The date '23-Oct-2016' is not required. Instead i have to get my existing date and do the conversion

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(11), CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '27-Jan-2011', 13), 103);
```

Comment: Not really, it will output as string dd\MM\yyyy format without any time component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

INSERT INTO SecondTable(Column1)

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(dt_of_birth AS DATETIME),103) FROM FirstTable