# SQL Convert String into DATETIME

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to (if its possible) convert a column that stores the date as a string in the following format `Monday October 19, 2015` to an usable datetime for example `01/10/2015`

Every cast and convert I have tried to run it through just returns

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Nothing I can do about the saved format as its part of a fixed process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chop off the day:

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(32) = 'Monday October 19, 2015'

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@S, CHARINDEX(' ', @S) + 1, LEN(@S)) AS DATETIME)

> 2015-10-19 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Clever. Didnt event think of stripping it down. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should manipulate the string to this format - "DD/MON/YYYY", where DD is day, MON is the first three letters of the months name, and YYYY is the year.
You could do that easily do that using string functions, and from there you can insert the date into the DB using conventional conversions, such as the ones listed in this post - [Convert DD-Mon-YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048856/convert-dd-mon-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy).